# Annotation to not serialize property if default value

Tags: serialization, jersey, jackson, moxy

I just started developing in Java and chose Jersey (2.4.1) as the framework I will use to build restful services.

When serializing a model, is there any annotation (moxy or jackson) to not serialize a property only if the value is default?

For example, in the case of reference types this would be `null`, but in the case of an `int` or `long`, the default value is `0`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. Using Jackson, you would use the following annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
public class User
{
...
}
```

Haven't figured out MOXy yet, however.

Comment: Quick note - if you're using Jackson 2.x - this has now been deprecated and replaced with: `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)`